# constant references with typedef and templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, reference, constants, temporary

I heard the temporary objects can only be assigned to constant references.

But this code gives error

```
#include <iostream.h>    
template<class t>
t const& check(){
  return t(); //return a temporary object
}    
int main(int argc, char** argv){

const int &resCheck = check<int>(); /* fine */
typedef int& ref;
const ref error = check<int>(); / *error */
return 0;
}
```

The error that is get is `invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'const int'`

Answer (score 20):

This:

```
typedef int& ref;
const ref error;
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. Consider instead:

```
typedef int* pointer;
typedef const pointer const_pointer;
```

The type of `const_pointer` is `int* const`, **not** `const int *`. That is, when you say `const T` you're saying "make a type where T is immutable"; so in the previous example, the pointer (not the pointee) is made immutable.

References cannot be made `const` or `volatile`. This:

```
int& const x;
```

is meaningless, so adding cv-qualifiers to references has no effect.

Therefore, `error` has the type `int&`. You cannot assign a `const int&` to it.

---

There are other problems in your code. For example, this is certainly wrong:

```
template<class t>
t const& check()
{
    return t(); //return a temporary object
}
```

What you're doing here is returning a reference to a temporary object *which ends its lifetime when the function returns*. That is, you get undefined behavior if you use it because there is no object at the referand. This is no better than:

```
template<class t>
t const& check()
{
    T x = T();
    return x; // return a local...bang you're dead
}
```

A better test would be:

```
template<class T>
T check()
{
    return T();
}
```

The return value of the function is a temporary, so you can still test that you can indeed bind temporaries to constant references.

Answer (score 7):

Your code gives error because the `const` qualifier in `const ref error` is just ignored because `8.3.2/1` says

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument(14.3), in which case the **cv-qualifiers are ignored**.`

So `error` has type `int&` not `const int&` .

Answer (score 7):

It's a very common mistake for English speaking people, because of the way the English grammar works.

I consider it extremely unfortunate that the C++ syntax would allow both:

```
const int // immutable int
int const // immutable int
```

to have the same meaning.

It doesn't make it easier, really, and isn't composable since:

```
const int* // mutable pointer to immutable int
int* const // immutable pointer to mutable int
```

certainly do NOT have the same meaning.

And this, unfortunately for you, what kicks in here, as @GMan explains.

If you wish to avoid this kind of error in the future, take the habit of qualifying your types (`const` and `volatile`) on their **right**, then you'll be able to treat a `typedef` as simple text replacement.

Answer (score 3):

To maintain consistency with the [Right Left Rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html), I prefer to use 'cv' qualifiers like so.

```
int const x = 2; // x is a const int (by applying Right Left rule)

int const *p = &x;  // p is a pinter to const int
```

In your example, I would write `const ref error = check<int>();` like so

```
ref const error = check<int>(); // parsed as error is a const reference to an integer
```

As @Prasoon Saurav pointed out, cv qualifiers are ignored when introduced through typedef because as @GMan also says, that cv qualified references are ill-formed.

Therefore the declaration is effectively as below, which of course is an error.

```
   int &error = check<int>();
```

Check out [this](http://www.dansaks.com/articles/1999-02%20const%20T%20vs%20T%20const.pdf) for more information.

Comment: This deserves a +1 because of the links given in the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is compiled:

```
typedef const int& ref; 
ref error = check<int>();
```

VC++ compiler gives some explanation of your error: qualifier applied to reference type; ignored. Reference type must be declared as constant, const cannot be applied later.