# Losing of 'const' modifier

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [constant references with typedef and templates in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801982/constant-references-with-typedef-and-templates-in-c)

Please look at the following code:

```
typedef wstring& RT;
RT Change(const RT v)
{
    v += L"234"; // why can I change this argument???

    return v;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    wstring str = L"111";
    wstring &str2 = Change(str);

    return 0;
}
```

I was surprised that argument 'v' in 'Change' function can be changed. We lose 'const' modifier. Metafunctions such as std::add_const do not help, could you please explain such behaviour?

Tool: VS2010

Comment: I disagree with the "exact duplicate".  The answer is essentially the same, but the other question implies that templates are part of the problem when it all boils down to typedefing.  For that reason, this version of the question may provide more benefit for people searching.

Answer (score 4):

It's sort of like precedence in an expression.  When you say

```
const wstring & foo;
```

it makes foo a reference to a constant wstring.  You can think of it like this:

```
(const wstring) & foo;
```

When you make a typedef, you've effectively changed the precedence.

```
const RT foo;
const wstring & foo;  // not equivalent, RT is a typedef, not a macro
const (wstring &) foo;  // this is effectively what happens
```

The const makes the foo const, not what the foo references.

Of course, as FredOverflow points out, a const reference is redundant, since you cannot assign to a reference, only to the object that it references.  So the result is that foo is just a plain old reference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `const` is simply ignored on the last line, because there is no such thing as a `const` reference.