# const_reference_type not compiling but const value_type& compiling

Tags: c++, gcc, constants

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct ref_exp{
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type& reference_type;
    typedef const reference_type const_reference_type;

    ref_exp(value_type data): _data(data){}
    const_reference_type data() const {return _data;}
  private:
    value_type _data;
};

int main(){
    ref_exp<int> exp1(2);
    std::cout << exp1.data() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code doesn't compile

```
ref.cpp: In member function ‘T& ref_exp<T>::data() const [with T = int]’:
ref.cpp:17:   instantiated from here
ref.cpp:10: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘const int’
```

But If I replace `const_reference_type data() const` with `const value_type& data() const` it works. Also If I replace `typedef const reference_type const_reference_type`

with `typedef const value_type& const_reference_type` it compiles

Comment: `const` in a `typedef` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [constant references with typedef and templates in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801982/constant-references-with-typedef-and-templates-in-c)

Comment: Can it be a `const (value_type&)` isn't the same as a `(const value_type)&` (braces inserted for clarification)?

Answer (score 6):

Your `const_reference_type` typedef does not do what you think:

```
typedef const reference_type const_reference_type;
```

`const_reference_type` is `int& const` - that is, the entire type `reference_type` has `const` applied to it - and a `const` reference cannot exist, so you get `int&`. You are not getting a `const int&` as you are expecting.

As you've noted, the fix here is to do:

```
typedef const value_type& const_reference_type;
```

The tip here is to not think of `typedef` as just a find-and-replace of type names, because it doesn't behave that way.

Comment: That is why I prefer to apply `const` on the right side rather than left side. It makes template code and typedefs easy to read.

Comment: @Nawaz: 100% agree. this is also suggested by Alexandrescu in his book on Modern C++ Design

Comment: @Nawaz: sorry, didn't see that one ;)

Comment: @sftrabbit: nitpicking : *"const_reference_type is **deduced** to be int& const."* There is no *deduction* here. It *is* `int & const`.

Answer (score 4):

`const reference_type` is indicating that the reference is const, not that the referenced object is const.

```
typedef int &int_ref;  // int_ref is a reference to a non-const int
typedef const int_ref int_ref_const; 
     // int_ref_const is a const reference to a non-const int
```

The const qualifier in the second case is basically a no-op, since references are implicitly const.

Think about a similar case with pointers:

```
typedef int *int_ptr; // int_ptr is a pointer to a non-const int
typedef const int_ptr int_ptr_const; 
    // int_ptr_const is a const pointer to a non-const int.
```

Answer (score 4):

In your typedef, `const reference_type` is **not** equal to `const value_type &` as you seem to think. It is rather `value_type & const` which is effectively `value_type &`.

**It is one reason why I prefer to apply `const` on the right side rather than left side**. If you write

```
reference_type const
```

then it would become immediately obvious that it is *actually* this:

```
value_type & const   //actually
```

*rather* than this:

```
value_type const &   //intended
```

It is clear now, isn't it?

Note that `value_type const &` and `const value_type &` are *same* type.

Anyway, to fix the problem you need to define the typedef as:

```
typedef value_type const & const_reference_type;
```

I prefer to apply `const` on the right side.