# std::copy: operator= not found

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm having a problem when using std::copy on Vector_t's initializer_list constructor. But as you can see in FixedPoint_t's declaration it has sufficient declarations for copy-construction and assignment. What signature does the compiler expect of me? Or am I missing something here? The compiler output points out that FixedPoint_t's operator= might fit, but it's still not used. There seems to be an issue with matching the argument list, too.

What I've tried:
Vector_t works for integral types and other classes, so it has to be some problem with FixedPoint_t.
The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/h1925w4w.aspx#United%20Kingdom%20(English)) page indicates a missing constructor. But FixedPoint_t's ctor matches.
FixedPoint_t's are assignable outside of Vector_t, but I can't draw a conclusion of it.
I could not reproduce the error with an int-wrapper I made.

Compiler: VS Compiler (VS 2015)
Error: C2679 Binary operator "=": No operator was found with rhs argument of type "const math::FixedPoint_t" (or no adequate conversion is possible)

### Test Code

```
#include <FpMath/FpMath.hpp>

using namespace math;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Vector object construction using an initializer_list
    Vector_t<FixedPoint_t<int, 4096>, 1> vec {
        4096
    };

    // Assignment outisde of Vector_t
    FixedPoint_t<int, 4096> fp1(3 * 4096);
    FixedPoint_t<int, 4096> fp2 = fp1; // works

    return 0;
}
```

### Vector.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algortihm> // std::copy

#include "FixedPoint.hpp"

namespace math {

    template <typename T, size_type size>
    class Vector_t {
    public:

        typedef T value_type;

        Vector_t(std::initializer_list<value_type> li);

    ...

    private:

        std::array<value_type, size> m_values;
    };

    template <typename T, size_type size>
    Vector_t<T, size>::Vector_t(std::initializer_list<value_type> li) : m_values() {

        assert(li.size() <= size);
        std::copy(li.begin(), li.end(), m_values.begin()); // < Error occurs here
    }
}
```

### FixedPoint.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>
#include <limits>

namespace math {

    template <typename T, T denom>
    class FixedPoint_t {
    public:

        typedef T value_type;
        typedef class_type& reference;

        FixedPoint_t();
        FixedPoint_t(const value_type& numerator);
        FixedPoint_t(const reference other);

        inline reference operator=(const reference other);
        inline reference operator=(const value_type& val);
    };
}
```

Comment: To the downvoter: could you please leave a comment on how to improve my question. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe they downvote because this is not a minimal example. Start removing unnecessary methods, typedefs, .... everything that is not needed. When you have the absolute minimum, post it here. Most likely you will also find the source of the problem, in that case post the solution as well.

Comment: And just in case change your MSDN link so that it will open English page. There is certain amount of people here who don't read German and don't want to bother with translation options

Comment: Also, apart from being minimal, the example must be complete. We have to be able to copy the sources, build it and reproduce the error. By omitting FixedPoint.tpp you prevent us from doing so. If it is too big, it's not a minimal example.

Comment: Should I edit this question further or delete and ask anew? thanks for your feedback.

Comment: `const reference != const class_type&`. (This is why prefix-`const` is misleading. I recommend using postfix-`const`.)

Comment: When you create the minimal example, do it on your machine. Remove one thing after another and test after each step. Doing so, you would figure out that the problem disappeared when you removed typedef - so there must be something wrong with it.

Comment: When answered, I would keep it as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
typedef class_type& reference;
...
FixedPoint_t(const reference other);
...
inline reference operator=(const reference other);
```

This construction does not declare const reference parameters. Change this to

```
typedef class_type& reference;
typedef const class_type& const_reference;
...
FixedPoint_t(const_reference other);
...
inline reference operator=(const_reference other);
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know you needed to typedef that and can't just combine.

Comment: Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801982/constant-references-with-typedef-and-templates-in-c